# How to find coefficient of in a binomial expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have to find coefficient of $x^3$ in $(x + 1)^n + (x + 1)^{n - 1}(x + 2) + (x + 1)^{n - 2}(x + 2)^2 + \ldots + (x + 2)^n$ and I cannot get a starting point as to how to solve this.

Comment: Hint: $a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=(a-b)(a^n+a^{n-1}b+\cdots+ab^{n-1}+b^n)$. Call $a=x+2$ and $b=x+1$.

Comment: @DiegoMath Thanks my brain has frozen at 5AM.

Answer (score 2):

We can start by simplifying the sum as follows but also note that we assume here $n\ge 3$,
$$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n (x+1)^{n-k}(x+2)^{k} = (x+2)^{n+1}-(x+1)^{n+1}$$
This can be derived with the help of finite geometric series. Now the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(x+a)^p$ is,
$$\displaystyle [x^r](a+x)^p  = \binom{p}{r}a^{p-r}$$
Using this the coefficient of $x^3$ is,
$$ \mathfrak{L} = \binom{n+1}{3}\left(2^{n-2}-1\right)$$
This is the required answer.